# "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map" in Safari for Angular2

Tags: angular, safari, typescript2.0

Getting error **"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map"** for **angular2** app in Safari browser only. Its working fine in other browsers. Using webpack for bundling files.

Angular Version: 2.1.0

Typescript: 2.0.3

Webpack : 1.13.2

When app is loading this error is coming in the browser console and preventing the app to load.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    devtool: "#source-map",
    entry: { vendors: './src/vendors', polyfills: './src/polyfills', app: './src/main.ts' },
    output: {
        path: './src/Builds/js',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].bundle.js.map",
        devtoolLineToLine: true,
        pathinfo: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              loader: 'ts'
          },
          {
              test: /\.json$/,
              loader: "json"
          }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Can you show your code where the error is shown? I think it should be map not Map if its about iteration.

Comment: Please add your webpack code. Thanks you.